# Docker Compose Wordpress example

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have been following the  [Quickstart Guide: Compose and Wordpress](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) and can't get it to work.

I think it has something to do with my directory structure. After running all the steps I had a sub-directory called `wordpress` but I think all of my code referenced a sub-directory called `code` so I decided to rename my `wordpress` directory `code`. I then re-run `docker-compose up` but this also unfortunately didn't work.

**UPDATE:** By *"can't get it to work"* when I enter load the website the PHP server returns:

```
Not Found
The requested resource / was not found on this server
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Could you please add some logs or console output?

Comment: Did you put your Dockerfile inside the extracted wordpress directory ?

Comment: @h3nrik I have updated the question, hopefully this clarifies your question

Comment: @Regan The Dockerfile is above the wordpress directory Here is a link to the directory structure http://pastebin.com/xTs6EfWR

Comment: @jamesmstone Can you upload your Dockerfile and your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @Regan here is  the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` http://pastebin.com/kFNH8die

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` should be inside your wordpress directory. (The one you renamed code)

### Your confusion

For some reason you think there is a code directory involved. There is no directory like that in your wordpress and it's **perfectly** normal.

Let's break down the command that are confusing you :

- In the `Dockerfile` :

`ADD . /code`

This line has for effect to copy the directory indicated (here it's . ) into the container directory indicated (here it's /code).

It's equivalent to a `cp` command only that you copy from the host to the container.

- In the `docker-compose.yml` :

`volumes:
    - .:/code`

This command is exposing a directory to a container. Here we expose the host directory . into the container directory /code.

Note : If you understood volume you might realize that the `ADD` instruction in your Dockerfile is unnecessary.

### Why it's not working

Your `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` are above the intended working directory.

So when the docker-compose execute it copy the content of your current directory into the /code directory of the container.

So when php try to execute in /code it doesn't see the file he expect hence the Not found error.

### Fix it

Either copy you `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` into the code directory (the one you renamed).

Or modify the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` so that they point to the good directory.

Answer (score 1):

By having a closer look to that quick start guide: The `Dockerfile` and the compose file should be inside your `wordpress` project folder that you created in the beginning. And also inside that `wordpress` folder there should be a sub-folder `code`. Run `docker-compose` from within the `wordpress` folder that way should work.

Unfortunately when you run the `curl https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz | tar -xvzf -` command from within your `wordpress` project folder it creates an other folder `wordpress` below your project directory. You should rename that one to `code`.

Comment: I updated my answer to be a bit more precise on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still gives the same error. 
Hopefully this might help.  Here is my what my file structure looks like: http://pastebin.com/xTs6EfWR this is from within the (parent) `wordpress`  directory aka project directory.